Movie about a guy writing / making a documentary about finding love who chooses to keep the cash instead?
I'm trying to find the name of a movie I watched many years ago. My memories of it are pretty vague though.
I'd estimate that the film was probably from the late 80's to the mid 90's, and almost certainly not into the 2000's. It was from North America... most likely the USA, and I think set somewhere on the west coast. It was about a guy who was either making a documentary or writing a newspaper article about looking for love / a girlfriend. He either narrated the movie or he may have even talked directly to camera.
He found the woman of his dreams but for some reason, he was faced with the ultimatum of staying with the girl, or winning / being given a large cash sum... I'm pretty sure it was $100,000. He decides to take the money.
Then comes the twist ending where he reveals that he took the money but he and the girl had carried on seeing each other in secret.
